# Regex replace in PHP to getting a number or a range after some prefixes

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have some texts with reference to lawsuit pages (folhas "fl. or fls." in portuguese) that I need to replace those numbers for a link (tag a) with an URL like:

`"localhost/m-n-i/consultarFolhas/".$page_start."/".$page_end`

Text examples:

- [...] **Fl. 53**: Considerando a manifestação do Estado, excluam-se os
  executados [...]
- [...] Nos termos das **FLS 10/ 44** estão [...]
- [...] Ao ERJ para se manifestar objetivamente sobre **fls. 88/92** [...]
- Às partes sobre resposta dos ofícios de **fls. 320/325** e **fls. 327/333**.
- [...] observadas as verbas que constam do documento **fls. 61** do [...]
- Documento de Atualização de Pensão (DAP) apresentado às **fls.61**, após sua contestação

As you can see some times they use plural (s) even for single pages but for multiple pages they normally use "/" to the separate the range.

I tried this Regex but it is still ineficiente to catch the situations described above:

```
const REGEX_FOLHAS = '#^.*\bfls?\. (\d+).*$#m';
```

So is it possible to create a REGEX to get those situations and replace with a hyperlink like this?

```
Nos termos das <a href='localhost/m-n-i/consultarFolhas/10/44/'> FLS 10/ 44 </a> estão

<a href='localhost/m-n-i/consultarFolhas/53/'>Fl. 53</a>: Considerando a manifestação do Estado, excluam-se os executados
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is almost what you want but you forgot some patterns and modifiers:

- Remove anchors and greedy dots (`m` flag too)
- Enable case-insensitivity (`i` flag)
- Make `\.` and following space characters optional: `\.? *`
- Write an optional pattern for slash separated digits `(?:\/ *\d+)?`
- Use capturing groups to extract data

Putting all together:

```
(?i)\bfls?\.? *(\d+)(?:(/) *(\d+))?
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdEeGk/1)

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('~(?i)\bfls?\.? *(\d+)(?:(/) *(\d+))?~', '<a href="localhost/m-n-i/consultarFolhas/$1$2$3">$0</a>');
```